# How to clear the margins of the corners of a checkbox in a listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox, margin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQOFb.png)
Please check the image.

There is a checkbox in the template in the listbox, and I set the red background color in it.

When I click on the red checkbox works fine.

But when I click on the image black arrow, it is not checked.

How can I clear the whitespace and synchronize it with the checkbox?

I tried setting margin padding but couldn't solve it.

```
        <ListBox x:Name="xList" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="red">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                          Content="{Binding Header}"
                          Height="28" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your `ListBox`:

```xml
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This will set the `Padding` of the `ListBoxItem` container to `0`. The result looks like this:

[image: result image]

Comment: I set it up in listbox and only in datatemplate. I hadn't thought of setting the listboxitem. Does this make a lot of difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but yes, it does make a difference. The `ItemContainerStyle` property enables you to alter the look of the container that holds your `DataTemplate`.